# Automatically send unpaid contribution reminder

Tags: civicontribute

I would like to send an email on the 10th of each month to "pay later" donors from the past month who did not pay their amount due.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Scheduled reminders](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/email/scheduled-reminders/) rather than CiviMail.